# Discord.Py bot will receive messages but doesn't respond

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

Discord.Py bot will receive messages but doesn't respond

Here is my code:

```
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands 

intents = discord.Intents.default()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    content = message.content
    user = message.author

    if user == client.user:
        return

    print("Received a message:", content)

    if content.strip() == "$hello":
        await message.channel.send("Hi!")

    if content.strip() == "$die":
        await message.channel.send("No you")
        client.close()


      
client.run(os.environ['Token'])
```

I have tried multiple different forms of code, none of which worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the [message_content](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=message_content#discord.Intents.message_content) intent to access the content of messages; to enable this, you need to enable the intent by going to:

> the [developer portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications) > select the bot > "Bot" section > enable the "message content" intent

[image]

Then you need to enable it in the code too to tell the Discord API that your bot needs to use it.

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True # set the "message_content" intent to "True"

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```